# Syntax error near unexpected token `else' for Travis build

Tags: bash, travis-ci

The following script works for me locally and I've put it through a bash linter, but Travis CI is complaining (I'm running it with `bash travis_release.sh`)

Here is the part it's complaining about:

```
#!/bin/bash
YEAR=$(date +"%Y")
MONTH=$(date +"%m")
git config --global user.email "${GIT_EMAIL}"
git config --global user.name "${GIT_NAME}"
git config --global push.default simple
git remote add origin https://${GH_TOKEN}@github.com/${TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG}.git
export GIT_TAG=$YEAR-$MONTH.$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER
git fetch --tags
msg="Tag Generated from TravisCI for build $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER"
if git tag "$GIT_TAG" -a -m "$msg" 2>/dev/null; then
git tag "$GIT_TAG" -a -m "Tag Generated from TravisCI for build $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER"
git push origin master && git push origin master --tags
ls -aR
else echo Tag already exists; fi
```

The error log is:

```
/home/travis/build/****/****/scripts/travis_release.sh: line 15: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
'
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this produces the observed syntax error, but you want to drop the `[ ... ]` from around the `git tag` command. `if git tag "$GIT_TAG" -a -m "$msg" 2>/dev/null; then`.

Comment: I've tried that too, unfortunately. Same error

Comment: Then the source of the error is likely in code *before* what you have posted.

Comment: @chepner I updated to include the whole file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that because I was editing this file in Windows, it became incompatible with Travis. A fix for this is to add `dos2unix` to your Travis pipeline by doing something like this in your `.travis.yml`:

```
script:
- dos2unix ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/scripts/*
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
    - dos2unix
```

Answer (score 1):

The only syntactically wrong bit is

```
if [ git tag $GIT_TAG -a -m "$msg" 2>/dev/null ]
```

which should possibly be

```
if git tag $GIT_TAG -a -m "$msg" 2>/dev/null
```

You also use unquoted variable expansions throughout the script.  These causes the values of the variables to undergo word splitting on whitespaces, and the shell will additionally perform filename globbing on their values.

For further help with cleaning up this script, I suggest that you paste it into [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and follow its suggestions.

Comment: I've updated the code that still generates the same error

Comment: @db2791 The error occurs on line 21. You are showing the first 15 lines.

Comment: @db2791 Apart from an unquoted variable expansion on line 7, there is nothing immediately wrong with the code. No syntax error.